# How to initialize tibble with difftime column

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I am getting error

```
Error in as.POSIXct(time1) : argument "time1" is missing, with no default
```

when I try to initialize tibble column with `difftime` class:

```
tibble(Time_diff = difftime())
```

Should I treat it as character and convert it to difftime once there're some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
tibble(Time_diff=structure(NA_real_, class = "difftime"))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Time_diff
  <drtn>   
1 NA
```

or

```
tibble(Time_diff=structure(NA_real_, class = "difftime")) %>% filter(FALSE)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 0 x 1
# … with 1 variable: Time_diff <drtn>
```

if you want an empty tibble containing a column of the required class?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do what you are trying to do is with `data.table::setattr`:

```
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
tibble(Time_diff = setattr(vector(),"class","difftime"))
## A tibble: 0 x 1
## … with 1 variable: Time_diff <drtn>
```

Is this necessary? Probably not.